# Adding 'stretch to' constraint on spring with target will change direction of spring

Tags: armature

I am trying to add a spring to my object's armature that will stretch and shrink. But when I apply the 'stretch to' constraint in the 'Apply constraint (with targets)' section, the spring suddenly changes the direction and is not aligned with its target (shown in pictures below). Could anyone fill me in on what I missed to have the spring align with the target?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have been following this tutorial (spring part starts at 8:52) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttNMGQLuz_w
and it seems that he manages to align the spring with the target, but I don't understand how he does it cause he doesn't explain the specific steps to align the object.

Comment: did you apply the rotation and scale in object mode (CTRL + A)?

Comment: No. But I did try it and its still not working. Could you tell me when and how I should apply rotation and scale?

Answer (score 2):

To fix this you have to Select your Spring and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> *to add Constraints (with Targets)* and choose "**Copy Transforms**" Constraint, this will add an empty were your mesh is and copy its Transforms this way giving your mesh the default: *location / scale / rotation* and for you to be able to change it, by *moving / scaling / rotating* your empty

[image]